# How do i make a centered "block of text"

Tags: html, css, center

this is HTML and CSS.

[image: This is how i want it to be:]

[image: and this is how it is now:]

this is my code:

```
p {
color: white;
text-align: center;
font-family: Helvetica;
}
```

with the correct paragraph syntax infront of this text and after this text: its glitching on stackoverflow for me idk y (im talking about the text under this line)

the upper image is how i *want* it to be and the lower image is how it currently *is*

Answer (score 1):

you have to assign a width to your paragraph. then add margin: auto;

```
p {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background-color: black;
    width:35%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:15px;
    }
```